# Saving the received bundle object when the activity is killed

Tags: android, bundle

I have a activity which is receiving the bundle in this manner:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String name = b.getString("NAME");
```

Now the user presses HOME button,consider that the activity is killed for some reason by the Android to free memory, so what happens to the bundle is that it gets NULL and the app FORCE CLOSES. How to avoid this?Is there any way to over come this?

How can i restore by bundle values ?

Comment: You *must* persist all data yourself on these state changes. Look for "Android Lifecycle".

Comment: what so you mean by urself?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data using the android

> protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)

This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state
please read the official documentation of this method

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)